# Ng-Select :- After Removing custom text should not be added in dropdownlist

Tags: jquery, css, angular, typescript, angular-ngselect

## I am adding a custom text in ng-select.When I am removing this text, It should not be added in dropdown list.

```
   <ng-select [items]="companies" [addTag]="addTagFn" [hideSelected]="true" multiple="true" bindLabel="name" [(ngModel)]="selectedCompanies">
</ng-select>



.ts file

    selectedCompanies;
    companies: any[] = [];
    companiesNames = ['Uber', 'Microsoft', 'Flexigen'];

    ngOnInit() {
        this.companiesNames.forEach((c, i) => {
            this.companies.push({ id: i, name: c });
        });
    }

    addTagFn(name) {
        return { name: name, tag: true };
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxC2y.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1nCo.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQtZi.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVTQg.png)

You can see in the last screenshot text is added in dropdown after removing I don't want this text in   dropdown after removing.could you please help me with simple solution.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please check this now